# Causal-cluster-friendly implementation

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-bolt

I am building an application that uses the native neo4j JavaScript driver.  I want to make sure that my code will work if we migrate to a causal cluster.

The online documentation doesn't seem to be clear about how to do this:  I notice sparse references to things like "bookmarks" and "reading what you have written", etc. But how it all fits together is unclear.

Can someone please provide a synopsis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use causal cluster you will need to change :

1) the url connection : replace `bolt://localhost:7687` by `bolt+routing://localhost:7687`

This will allow your application to make some LB query to the cluster, and be fault tolerant without doing anything else

2) When you open a new session, you should specified what you will do into this session, ie. READ or WRITE.
This will help the driver to choose the good server (ie a core or a replica server). Otherwise it assumes you will do some WRITE operations, and the driver will always choose a core server ...

3) because you will be on a cluster env., there is some lag (some secondes) for the propagation of an update inside the cluster.
Or sometimes, you need to `read your own writes` within two sessions. It's where you will need the bookmark functionality.

Documentation is here : https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/drivers/

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful, according to the documentation that you referenced above, I would expect to see an access-mode argument for the session() method in the Driver class in https://neo4j.com/docs/api/javascript-driver/current/class/src/v1/driver.js~Driver.html#instance-method-session , what am I missing?

Comment: That seems to be referring to v1 of the driver. The latest is v1.1. See here - https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver/blob/1.1/lib/v1/driver.js#L174

Comment: Thank you.  That is what I needed!